# With selectizeInput, stop the list of choices from closing after each selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to include a selectizeInput widget in a Shiny app.  However, one aspect of its behavior is problematic: each time I make a selection, the box containing the choices closes.

I took a look at the example app here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html.  Specifically, input number 2: Multi-select.  The selection window remains open in this example, yet I see no differences between that code and mine which would account for the variance in behavior.

For the sake of a reproducible example, I have put together the following code:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(uiOutput("example")) 

  server <- function(input, output, session){

                    output$example <- renderUI({

                                       selectizeInput(
                                                     inputId="people", 
                                                     label=NULL,
                                                     choices=paste("A", 1:50, sep="_"),
                                                     multiple = TRUE,
                                                     selected=input$people
                                                     )

                                                })

 } # close server

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

My guess is that I'm missing something obvious, so here's a chance for an easy answer for someone that knows their way around Shiny.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the `selected=input$people` line, it works as intended.